# Mandrill smtp failures

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, mandrill

I'm having enormous difficulty getting mandrill SMTP to send reliably. Or more accurately, authenticate every time. When it does authenticate the email works fine

I can run the send script fine, then 2 or 3 times in succession one after the other. Then it doesn't authenticate.  But on occasions it doesn't authenticate straight away.

I thought perhaps it's just because it thinks I'm abusing it and blocked me for a short period.

But I can see that since I started using mandrill SMTP for my website, its failure rate to authenticate is regular.

Tried SPF and dmik text attributed on the domain. This didn't help

Looking around I can't see other people having this issue, but at this rate I certainly can't use mandrill for SMTP.

Can anyone suggest reasons why this could be happening? My credentials are 100% accurate, and I don't think I'm sending many emails at all.

Having the same problem on another server using another mandrill account.

Note: I'm using phpmailer

Example debug error:

```
2014-12-06 08:52:59 Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:587, t=300, opt=array (
)
2014-12-06 08:52:59 Connection: opened
2014-12-06 08:52:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP
2014-12-06 08:52:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO fakemail.com
2014-12-06 08:52:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-ip-10-243-6-11
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 26214400
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
2014-12-06 08:52:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2014-12-06 08:52:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2014-12-06 08:52:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWVAZG91Z25vcmZvbGsuY29tLmF1
2014-12-06 08:52:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2014-12-06 08:52:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: REDACTED
2014-12-06 08:53:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2014-12-06 08:53:01 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2014-12-06 08:53:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2014-12-06 08:53:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
2014-12-06 08:53:01 Connection: closed
2014-12-06 08:53:01 SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Example correct send:

```
2014-12-06 08:52:33 Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:587, t=300, opt=array (
)
2014-12-06 08:52:33 Connection: opened
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO fakemail.com
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-ip-10-250-28-124
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 26214400
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWVAZG91Z25vcmZvbGsuY29tLmF1
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: REDACTED
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<me@fakemail.com>
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<me@fakemail.com>
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Sat, 6 Dec 2014 19:52:33 +1100
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Test <me@fakemail.com>
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Test <me@fakemail.com>
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Here is the subject
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <0a8f3c40575be98668d8ea6fb03f4bfc@fakemail.com>
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:   boundary="b1_0a8f3c40575be98668d8ea6fb03f4bfc"
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_0a8f3c40575be98668d8ea6fb03f4bfc
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_0a8f3c40575be98668d8ea6fb03f4bfc
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_0a8f3c40575be98668d8ea6fb03f4bfc--
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 109BC180070
2014-12-06 08:52:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2014-12-06 08:52:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
2014-12-06 08:52:33 Connection: closed
Message sent!
```

I tried firing the email every 5 seconds. 3 out of 10 times it didn't send.

1 minute later, i tried every 10 seconds. 8 out of 10 didn't send.

Comment: Can you provide specifics of the authentication error you're getting, and also log details about the IP address that you're connecting to when you get the error(s)? In general, if you're able to log the full SMTP conversations for each connection, that often can provide the level of detail needed to determine what's happening or give a good starting point.

Comment: my bad, see added error code. Thanks for your response, would love to use Mandrill, just can't understand this issue

Comment: updated to latest phpmailer - SMTPDebug = 3

Comment: I edited the debug info to redact the password info, but I'd recommend disabling that API key in any case to be on the safe side. It definitely looks like you're connecting to a Mandrill server properly though. Can you check to see if the line that looks like this: `2014-12-06 08:52:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-ip-10-243-6-11` is the same for all of the failed sends, and/or if you see the same IP for any successful sends (or any patterns for those because that shows which Mandrill server you're connecting to)?

Comment: I deleted that api now. Ill inspect based on your suggestion

Comment: I actually was able to replicate the auth failed issue with the one specific server included in your error log above and escalated to our engineering team to see if there's an issue syncing credentials to that server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66340/discussion-between-kaitlin-mandrill-and-cardi777).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's intermittent, it certainly looks like a problem at their end. Set `SMTPDebug = 3` to see the whole SMTP conversation.

From the one-sided view you've given, it doesn't look like you're using TLS, and it's common not to allow authentication prior to starting TLS, though I can see that the server is saying it will do it. I'd regard allowing auth without TLS as a security flaw, certainly not something you need to allow.

Also make sure you're using latest PHPMailer (5.2.9+).