# Mandrill : SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, mandrill

I have below configuration to send mass email to 50 clients in one hour.

SMTP Provider : Mandrill

Hourly Quota : 380 emails/ hr

Mail Box  Reputation  : Good and not spamming

PHPMailer : Version 5

**Issue**: When I execute script, sometime it sends mails to each of 50 customers while sometime, it stopped sending mails saying :

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

It resumes automatically and send emails to remaining clients.

**My Code**:

```
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST;
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->setFrom(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_NAME);

    For Loop{
    $msgHTML = "<table width='500px;' align='center'>";
    $msgHTML .= "<tr><td>Dear Customer</td></tr>";
    $msgHTML .= "</table>";


    $mail->addReplyTo();
    $mail->addAddress();
    $mail->Subject = 'Loan Request Follow Up from xyzdummy.com.';
    $mail->msgHTML($msgHTML);
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    try{
    $mail->send();
    echo "Mail Sent to ->".$forloop[$j]['EmailId'] ;
    }
    catch (phpmailerException $e) 
    { 
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    echo "Mail Failed to ->".$forloop[$j]['EmailId'] ;
    }


    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearCCs();
    $mail->clearBCCs();     
    }   
    }
```

Output when

```
            Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:25, t=10, opt=array ()
            Connection: opened
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP
            CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO smtp.mandrillapp.com
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 26214400"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 8BITMIME"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250 8BITMIME"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250 8BITMIME
            CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            bl abla
            CLIENT -> SERVER: 
            CLIENT -> SERVER: .
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D1D682A0B20"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D1D682A0B20"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D1D682A0B20
            CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 Bye"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "221 2.0.0 Bye"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
            Connection: closed



            Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:25, t=10, opt=array ()
            SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
            SMTP connect() failed.
            SMTP connect() failed.

            Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:25, t=10, opt=array ()
            SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
            SMTP connect() failed.
            SMTP connect() failed.


            Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:25, t=10, opt=array ()
            SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
            SMTP connect() failed.
            SMTP connect() failed.

            SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
            SMTP connect() failed.
            SMTP connect() failed.

            Connection: opening to smtp.mandrillapp.com:25, t=10, opt=array ()
            Connection: opened
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP
            CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO smtp.mandrillapp.com
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 26214400"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 8BITMIME"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250 8BITMIME"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-relay-2.ap-southeast-1.mandrill-relay-prod250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 26214400250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250 8BITMIME
            CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            bl abla
            CLIENT -> SERVER: 
            CLIENT -> SERVER: .
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D1D682A0B20"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D1D682A0B20"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D1D682A0B20
            CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 Bye"
            SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "221 2.0.0 Bye"
            SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
            Connection: closed
```

I can run the send script fine, then 2 or 3 times in succession one after the other. It works fine but then suddenly fails to connect

I asked question as comment on [Mandrill smtp failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326653/mandrill-smtp-failures/29605958#29605958) . I was suggested to raise a new question on site.

I dont know where to fix apart from adding

$phpMailer->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  and $phpMailer->SmtpClose();  before and after for loop.

However, I am not sure whether this is the right approach or not?

You pointers to solve above issue will be highly apprecaited.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That does look like a mandrill problem - you're doing everything right in PHPMailer. They may be using round-robin DNS to spread connections over a pool of servers, and one or more of them could be down. There isn't really anything you can do at your end if their servers are not working properly. The only real fallback would be for you to use a local mail server and set it up to relay through mandrill. That would take care of queueing and retrying the sends, and also make your app able to get on with other things as sending would be asynchronous.

You should definitely use `SMTPKeepAlive` - it will make sending much more efficient and reduce the likelihood of this problem occurring (because it will only use one server).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your local environment, this could also be because your hosting provider or ISP limits outbound SMTP connections. Some have rate limits, or will redirect connections if you exceed certain limitations. It's also possible you have stale DNS records for smtp.mandrillapp.com which would result in your system trying to access smtp.mandrillapp.com on an IP address that is no longer in use for that host name. You could use a tool like Wireshark to actually track the specific IPs that you're connecting to (or attempting to connect to). There may also be more verbose logging available with PHPMailer, but you'd want to see more details about *where* you're trying to connect to determine the issue.